# Error with ostream definition

Tags: c++, clang++, ostream

Doing some refactoring, I get an error after moving some code in a class' member function:

```
std::ostream  logStream;         //  <-- error
std::filebuf  fileBuffer;

// Send the output either to cout or to a file
if(sendToCout) {
    logStream.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
}
else {
    fileBuffer.open("out.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ofstream::app);
    logStream.rdbuf(&fileBuffer);
}

logStream << "abcd..." << std::endl;
```

This is the compiler error message:

```
file.cpp:417: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'std::__1::basic_ostream<char>'
        std::ostream  logStream;
                      ^
```

Could this be a solution?

```
std::filebuf  fileBuffer;
std::ostream  logStream(&fileBuffer);

...

if(sendToCout) {
    logStream.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
}
```

Comment: Check the [available constructor calls](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream). You need to pass the `fileBuffer` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If you see e.g. [this `std::ostream` constructor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) you will see that the only public constructor is one taking a pointer to a [`std::streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) object, like for example your variable `fileBuffer`.

So one way to solve your problem is to do

```
std::filebuf  fileBuffer;
std::ostream  logStream(&fileBuffer);
```

A better solution is to use [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) if you want output to a file.

If you want a more generic solution, where it should be possible to use any kind of output stream, then a redesign to use *references* instead is a possible solution.

Or, you know, try and find an existing logging library which handles everything for you already.

Comment: I extended my question on the basis of your answer. Could it work?